# GridView.getCheckedItemPositions() does not return correct values

Tags: android

I am making an application in which i can select/deselect images .  , when i select all images once

`GridView.getCheckedItemPositions()` returns correct value. but if i deselect any item this method does not return updated values.

Here is my code .

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(GalleryImages.this, "position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ActionMode mode =startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                 mode.setTitle(gridView.getCheckedItemCount() + " Selected");
                 Toast.makeText(GalleryImages.this, ""+gridView.getCheckedItemPositions().size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

final ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                mode=null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                layoutForAlertDialog = (LayoutInflater) GalleryImages.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View view = layoutForAlertDialog.inflate(R.layout.addtag_dialog, null);
                alertForTag = new AlertDialog.Builder(GalleryImages.this);
                alertForTag.setTitle("Enter Name Tag");
                alertForTag.setView(view);
                alertForTag.create();
                alertForTag.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });
                alertForTag.show();
                return true;
            }

        };
```

Comment: And is `gridView.getCheckedItemCount()` correct? Why are you posting the Actionmode.Callback code? Has it anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Yes gridView.getCheckedItemCount() is showing correct value. plz have a look at this image path   http://www.imagesup.net/?di=414152763543

Comment: @greenapps I have used object ob callback ,that's why i posted callback method .

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand you. For what did you use it? But really i don't have to know if it has nothing to do with your problem. I asked already.

Comment: @greenapps okay my mistake . i should have not posted that code . so have got my problem ? plz visit this link http://www.imagesup.net/?di=414152763543      . This would help you understanding this problem

Comment: In which way do you make the items in your gridview selectable? I see a checkmark in your action bar too.

Comment: To make Gridview selectable , i used this code .



gridView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" >

</RelativeLayout >

Comment: I see now that you don't look at getCheckedItemPositions() but at getCheckedItemPositions().size(). Please tell what happens when you start app again and select more and more items. Do you have more items then fitt the screen?